# Custom Templates/Forms for Django Comments

Tags: python, django, forms, templates, comments

How would I make my own custom templates/forms for the built in Django Comments Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to override (specific) templates put them in **templates/comments** (a technique not only valid for contrib.comments but for [all reusable apps](http://ericholscher.com/projects/django-conventions/project/) including [Django's admin](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates).).

If you want to edit the builtin forms you have to extend contrib.comments as mentioned and [explained in the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/custom/).